# Google Drive API multipart upload gets file corrupted

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, postman, multipart

I've been trying to upload a file using the Google Drive API but I'm facing an issue and I can't seem to find the answer.
This happens when uploading an image, with text files, it seems to be ok.

Following the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads
I need to form the request like this

[image: Google Drive API]

I've tried either from POSTMAN or from Salesforce Apex and got the same issue.

I'm sending the image encoded as Base64, but the images are not getting decoded on the Google Drive side, so the issue is that there is no preview and can't open the file. If I download the file and open it on a text editor, the content is just text.

[image: postman]

This is the image opened from VS Code

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are trying to upload the base64 data. So how about this modification?

#### Modified request body:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN]
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=foo_bar_baz
Content-Length: [NUMBER_OF_BYTES_IN_ENTIRE_REQUEST_BODY]

--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
  "name": "myObject"
}

--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64   <--- Added this.

[JPEG_DATA]
--foo_bar_baz--
```

- Please add `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64` to the data part.

#### Reference:

- [Upload files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)

If this didn't resolve your issue, I apologize.

Comment: That was it, found it before reading your answer by uploading manually to google drive and checking the requests in the console. Would be good if that was included in the GDrive doc itself. That would have saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Also the other issue I was having was line breaks. If you add one additional line break that is not expected it breaks everything and it doesn't decode the base64 data and instead it stores a text file

Comment: @Federico Giust Thank you for replying. Yes. I think so. When I had looked for the document related to this, I had not found it. I think that when such document is added, it will be useful for users. And, the line breaks are important for the request body.